# How can I get class-based objects in JavaScript with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I'm trying to move from Prototype to jQuery and there's one last thing I can't figure out how to do in the new library.

Here's what I used to do with Prototype:

```
MyClass = Class.create();

MyClass.prototype = {
  initialize: function(options) {
  }
}
```

Then I could create a new `MyClass` with:

```
var mc = new MyClass({});
```

Does jQuery have anything like Prototype's `Class.create()`? And if not, how do I get the same kind of thing without a library?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use the jquery [extend](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend) function to extend a class prototype.

For example:

```
MyWidget = function(name_var) {
  this.init(name_var);
}

$.extend(MyWidget.prototype, {
   // object variables
   widget_name: '',

   init: function(widget_name) {
     // do initialization here
     this.widget_name = widget_name;
   },

   doSomething: function() {
     // an example object method
     alert('my name is '+this.widget_name);
   }
});

// example of using the class built above
var widget1 = new MyWidget('widget one');
widget1.doSomething();
```

Note: I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84716/is-there-a-better-way-to-create-an-object-oriented-class-with-jquery) about this same topic.

Comment: So how was this question answered way before it was asked?

Comment: @AndresRiofrio: two questions were merged.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery uses the standard javascript functionality for creating new classes.

There are some fine examples on the web, but I would recommend looking at David Flanagan's books Javascript: The Definitive Guide.

[Object-Oriented JavaScript](http://nefariousdesigns.co.uk/archive/2006/05/object-oriented-javascript/)

[JavaScript and Object Oriented Programming (OOP)](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml)

---

I apologize, I completely misunderstood your original post.  I'm guessing that you actually want to know how to extend the jQuery $ object.  This is easily doable, there are a large number of plugins out there for doing so.  There is a tutorial on the jQuery site for doing this: [Getting Started With jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Plug_me:_Writing_your_own_plugins)

Essentially, though, you use

```
 jQuery.fn.foobar = function() {
   // do something
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't define OOP primitives, so you are on your own. But it is easy to do what you want with plain JavaScript:

```
MyClass = function(options){
  // whatever were in your initialize() method
};
```

And you can create instances like you used to:

```
var mc = new MyClass({});
```

If you used to have more things in the prototype you can add them like you used to:

```
MyClass.prototype = {
  // no need for initialize here anymore
  /*
  initialize: function(options) {
  },
  */

  // the rest of your methods
  method1: function() { /*...*/ },
  method2: function() { /*...*/ }
}
```

Alternatively you can add your methods dynamically:

```
$.extend(MyClass.prototype, {
  method1: function() { /*...*/ },
  method2: function() { /*...*/ }
});
```

And finally you can provide your very own class creator:

```
var CreateClass = function(){
  return function(){ this.initialize.apply(this, arguments); };
};

// the rest is a copy from your example

MyClass = CreateClass();

MyClass.prototype = {
  initialize: function(options) {
  }
}

var mc = new MyClass({});
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, a regular function acts as a constructor if used with 'new' keyword.

So you can do,

```
function MyClass(options)
{
   this.options = options;
};

MyClass.prototype.initialize = function() { } ;

MyClass.prototype.sayHello = function() { alert('Hello!'); };

var item = new MyClass( { id : 10 } );
item.sayHello(); //alerts Hello!
alert(item.options.id); //alerts 10.
```

I would suggest that you try to understand how JavaScript actually works. Try to [understand prototype inheritance as opposed to class based inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816071/prototype-based-vs-class-based-inheritance). Good understanding of JavaScript will help you exploit the power of the language.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically copy the relevant part from prototype's source code and leave the parts about extending. 
http://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/add69978e09653808aedec43ed551df22818ee30/src/lang/class.js

jQuery doesn't have such a system for object creation and extension, since the whole system seems to depend on jQuery chaining (to jeresig: sorry if I'm mistaken). So you have to create your own system anyway.

To get an idea, Douglas Crockford has a well known pattern for creating objects and inheritance in JavaScript.
http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: jQuery internally relies on JavaScript's native prototype-based OO model, lightly augmented using jQuery's $.extend() function. Most jQuery client code i've seen tends to follow this model as well, but you certainly could add in the quasi-class systems used by Prototype or similar... Note that in your last link, Crockford admits his earlier attempts at a class-based system were largely misguided, and argues for embracing JavaScript's native OO, something closer to the jQuery model.

Comment: I thought the question was more about switching libraries without changing the original codebase. $.extend() wasn't going to call Function.initialize() so I thought of a custom solution. Not as good as $.extend, though :-)

Answer (score 1):

A good solution by John Resig:
[Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use standard JavaScript:

```
MyClass = function(options) {
  console.log(options);
};

var mc = new MyClass([1,2,3]);
```

You can use jQuery to provide inheritance: http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend#deeptargetobject1objectN

Answer (score 0):

you can try JS.Class (portable, modular JavaScript class library) - http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think, theres an easyer way ...

```
    function Dashboard() {
    var dashboard = this;
    dashboard.version = 'Version 0.1';
    dashboard.__init = function() {
            console.log('init');
    };
    dashboard.__init();
}
var dash = new Dashboard();

will log 'init'
```

Answer (score -1):

Never done it, but I imagine looking at some of the plug-ins such as Thickbox might be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

John Resig's fantastic Classy Query plugin provides exactly what you're looking for:

http://ejohn.org/blog/classy-query/

Comment: I believe that is an april fools joke.