# Alternate of prototype Class.create();

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototypejs, zepto

is there an alternate of Class.create(); of Prototype.js, i have found a code to call SOAP Webservice and return javascript object and i want to implement that in to my mobile website but don't want to use prototype because i m using Zepto and Backbone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this: [Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) by John Resig. He has another blog on class instantiation which has good explanation on this topic: [Simple "Class" Instantiation](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/).

Also, check out this post on JavaScript inheritance: [Is there a better way to create an object-oriented class with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84716/is-there-a-better-way-to-create-an-object-oriented-class-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many libraries that provide syntactic sugar to create new object types in javascript. My favorite is [my.class](https://github.com/jiem/my-class). But if you want to call a SOAP web service, that has next to no relation to defining a class. It's entirely possible that you don't want a class at all:

- Will there only be one instance? use an object literal.
- Is the only difference what DOM elements will be acted upon? Perhaps a jQuery plugin is a better fit. (Zepto tries to be API-compatible with jQuery.)