# Run function attached to jQuery object

Tags: jquery, function

I've created a function that I'd like to be able to call on an object like other methods do;

```
$(object).myfunction(value);
```

I'm not sure how to structure my function to bind to the object part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choice, eather you extend the class of the object and had your function like this:

```
var MyWidget = Class.extend({
  init: function(widget_name){
    this.widget_name = widget_name;
  },

  doSomething: function() {
    alert('my name is ' + this.widget_name);
  }
});
MyWidget.doSomething();
```

otherwise you create a function and pass the object as parameter, like this:

```
my_function =function(my_object1, my_object2){
   // do something
}
myfunction(my_object1, my_object2)
```

from:

[Is there a better way to create an object-oriented class with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84716/is-there-a-better-way-to-create-an-object-oriented-class-with-jquery)